# postgresql invalid input syntax for type double precision

Tags: sql, postgresql, to-timestamp

I have a table with the birth and death of several europe monarchs, the table doesn't have have an age column and i have to add it. There are also several null and 'None' values, in that case the age column should display unknow.

the following code gives me a `invalid input syntax for type double precision` error.

```
    SELECT CASE
WHEN date_part('year', age(TO_TIMESTAMP(death, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_TIMESTAMP(birth, 'YYYY-MM-DD'))) = 'None' OR death ISNULL
    THEN 'Unknown'
ELSE
    date_part('year', age(TO_TIMESTAMP(death, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_TIMESTAMP(birth, 'YYYY-MM-DD')))
END
```

AS age
FROM monarchs

postgresql doesn't have a datediff function. Many thanks.

**EDIT**

The birth and death columns are varchars and have this format `0208-10-01T00:53:28+00:53`

Comment: **Never** store timestamp values in `varchar` columns. You should fix that broken data model before you proceed

Comment: what data type do you recomend? i need it to be compatible with the case statement

Comment: `timestamp` or `timestamptz`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resolved**

Used the following code

```
CASE 
   WHEN death IS NULL OR birth IS NULL
      THEN 'Unknown'
      ELSE CAST(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_TIMESTAMP(death, 'YYYY-MM-DD')) - EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_TIMESTAMP(birth, 'YYYY-MM-DD')) AS VARCHAR)
END
```

'null' is a string. My query was doing a substraction and case statements needs to be of the same data type so I had to typecast it to varchar.